# Page get redirected on Google Adwords Conversion Tracking

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, google-ads-api, vue-resource

I've form where people submit data and the data is sent to the server using ajax. I've setup this as a conversion in Google Adwords. Below is the code that I've used.

The problem is, when a user submits the form, after getting the response, its redirected back to URL that I've given. I don't want to redirect!!

(Data submitted is using Vue-resource since this project is in VueJS)

```
submit() {
  let self = this
  this.$validator.validateAll().then(success => {
    if (!success) {
      return;
    }
    document.getElementById("submitQuote").value = "Submitting...";
    this.$http.post(store.state.url+'api/submit_quote.php', {
        formData: store.state.formData
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.submitted = true
        self.reference_id = response.data
        goog_report_conversion('https://www.example.com/') //report Google that a conversion has occured
      });
  });
}
```

Code given by Google

```
<!-- Google Code for Add to Cart Conversion Page
    In your html page, add the snippet and call goog_report_conversion
    when someone clicks on the chosen link or button. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
     /* <![CDATA[ */
    goog_snippet_vars = function() {
      var w = window;
      w.google_conversion_id = 12345678;
      w.google_conversion_label = "abcDeFGHIJklmN0PQ";
      w.google_conversion_value = 13.00;
      w.google_conversion_currency = "USD";
      w.google_remarketing_only = false;
    }
    // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
    goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
      goog_snippet_vars();
      window.google_conversion_format = "3";
      var opt = new Object();
      opt.onload_callback = function() {
      if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
        window.location = url;
      }
    }
    var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
    if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
      conv_handler(opt);
      }
        }
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
    </script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just don't provide a redirect URL to `goog_report_conversion`, i.e. call it without parameters.

The redirect is conditional:

```
if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
    window.location = url;
}
```

Comment: But why do google write above this code "// DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW."?

Comment: I'm not suggesting to change that code, but to call `goog_report_conversion()` without a parameter. To answer your question, it's probably to make it less likely that a non tech-savvy user will unwittingly render the script inoperative while inserting it into a web page.

Comment: If you call goog_report_conversion() without a parameter, will adwords be able to get the url of the page where the conversion took place?