# Google DoubleClick onclick event goog_report_conversion always opens hyperlink with target="_blank" in current AND new tab

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, href, double-click-advertising

I have this URL:

```
<a rel="external nofollow" href="http://prf.hn/click/camref:1101l337I/creativeref:1101l14808/destination:https://www.wehkamp.nl/Winkelen/KenmerkAdviseurArtikel.aspx?CC=C50&amp;SC=IUB&amp;KAC=C76&amp;artikelNummer=766344&amp;MaatCode=0000&amp;BC=PHGBaby_766344&amp;utm_campaign=affiliates_productfeed_Fiets_Baby&amp;dfw_tracker=22685-86766344" onclick="goog_report_conversion ('http://prf.hn/click/camref:1101l337I/creativeref:1101l14808/destination:https://www.wehkamp.nl/Winkelen/KenmerkAdviseurArtikel.aspx?CC=C50&amp;SC=IUB&amp;KAC=C76&amp;artikelNummer=766344&amp;MaatCode=0000&amp;BC=PHGBaby_766344&amp;utm_campaign=affiliates_productfeed_Fiets_Baby&amp;dfw_tracker=22685-86766344');productclick(3374956,'85-86766344');return true;" target="_blank" class="btn-primary-green" style="font-size:14px;">Shop now <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

When I click this link, it opens in a new tab, but at the same time also opens in the existing tab.

When I remove the onclick attribute, like below, it worked correctly:

```
<a rel="external nofollow" href="http://prf.hn/click/camref:1101l337I/creativeref:1101l14808/destination:https://www.wehkamp.nl/Winkelen/KenmerkAdviseurArtikel.aspx?CC=C50&amp;SC=IUB&amp;KAC=C76&amp;artikelNummer=766344&amp;MaatCode=0000&amp;BC=PHGBaby_766344&amp;utm_campaign=affiliates_productfeed_Fiets_Baby&amp;dfw_tracker=22685-86766344" target="_blank" class="btn-primary-green" style="font-size:14px;">Shop now <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

I tried removing the `productclick` function in the onclick event, the problem persists. But when I remove the `goog_report_conversion` and keep the `productclick` function in the onclick, the problem is gone. It seems the problem really is related to the `goog_report_conversion` call. I get no errors in the console or network tab.

I also tried removing the onclick event altogether and run the onclick code in a jQuery onclick event, but even then the link opens in the same tab AND a new tab.

How can I make sure the link does not also open in the current tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the issue is happening is because the goog_report_conversion calls the target url once we click the link

```
goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
      goog_snippet_vars();
      window.google_conversion_format = "3";
      var opt = new Object();
      opt.onload_callback = function() {
      if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
        window.location = url; // <--- this will load the url to be tracked again after the click
      }
    }
```

Reference: 
https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6331304?hl=en

It was designed like that so the links can be tracked. Once you move to a new window it's not possible to track that link.

So the issue can't be resolved just by some hack. If you change the goog_report_conversion code then your calls won't be tracked.

What you need to do is use Google Tag manager which will track the events.

Update: Found a link which describes the same

https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/AdWords-Tracking-and-Reporting/Conversion-tracking-onclick-when-it-opens-a-new-window/td-p/444548#

Comment: I intended to mention [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42554607/6730571) in a comment, but on the test page linked in question, if I remove the argument to `goog_report_conversion()`, I still get the undesirable effect (redirects current page + opens in new tab)... so I thought there might be more at play. Or maybe my test is invalid... anyway, thought you'd be interested.

Comment: How are you removing the argument? from developer tools?

Comment: Yes... maybe that's not a valid way in this case? (If invalid or irrelevant I can remove my comments, if you think it can cause confusion)

Comment: If you are typing events from developer tools it adds the new event listener as an additional event listener. I think we can have the comment here. So it will help other users when they are trying like this.

Comment: @HuguesMoreau You can play around here https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/g01cbcof/ . Modify alert('hi') to something else you will see 'Hi' printing first and then the new handler

Comment: Wow... I thought there was only one 'inline onclick' listener. Indeed editing it in the DOM only *adds a new one*. If however I get a handle on the link element in the JS console, then do `link.onclick=null`, and then `link.onclick="productclick(2725086,'24-10100934');goog_report_conversion();return true;"` it works: the old listener is gone, the new tab opens, and the current page is not relocated. Thanks!

Comment: @karthick thank you! So you're saying I should remove the `goog_report_conversion` from the onclick event and setup a custom event tracker in Google Tag Manager so at least my AdWords will still report on conversions (I've never used GTM before)? And do you know why my post is getting downvoted?

Comment: Yes that's the way to go. If you want to open external links in new window. Someone might have initially down voted and slept. :-)